# I need Bluetooth-enabled keyboard and mouse?

Tags: usb, keyboards, mice, bluetooth

I need a keyboard and a mouse. They should run on Bluetooth, but be chargeable via USB as well, if that's possible? Preferable both in one go.

Price limit: INR 1000/-.

Bluetooth essential.
Price essential.
Chargeable desirable.

Comment: For that price, which is $14.94 USD as of this posting.....you are not going to find much of anything with any reliable worth mentioning